# What is the name of the data member of an object "cin" which stores an input data in C++?

Tags: c++, buffer, cin

Eg. cin>>var;
Object cin reads input data from the user and as soon as the ENTER key is hit, the operator ">>" extracts the contents of cin and stored into the specific variable "var". That means the input data were first stored in the cin object.

Now, if cin stores the data, then I'm curios to know to which MEMBER DATA of the cin object will the inputted data will be stored??? Eg. cin.memberdataname or cin.xxxx etc?? What is the name of the member data where the inputted data are first initially stored?

Comment: `std::cin` does not store any data, it's unbuffered, a terminal window sends an input data after Enter is pressed.

Comment: Terminal window means?  Could you kindly explain in layman terms please ?

Comment: How std::cin does things internally is totally up to the implementation. But usually it involves having a (circular) memory buffer, and usually access to this buffer is very limited. Have you read the documentation on [basic_ios::rdbuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) yet? It is usually best to first consult cppreference before asking questions ;)

Comment: `cin` doesn't store any data. It has an associated `streambuf` object, and cin's default `streambuf` object reads in and buffers data from the terminal window that you are typing into. Then `operator>>` reads from the `streambuf`. This is fundamental to how streams work in C++, since streams can be swapped around without changing how the operators work with them

Comment: You are right that the input data is stored somewhere, but you are wrong in thinking that it must be stored in the `cin` object. C++ does not specify where this data is stored.

Answer (score 1):

It's left entirely unspecified by the C++ language *how* `std::cin` (or rather, it's associated `std::streambuf` implementation) reads data from the standard input stream.  The only thing C++ specifies is that it does so (and that, by default, that reading is synchronized with the C stdio functions like `scanf`, `fread`, and friends).

The common approach is for `std::cin`'s `std::streambuf` to internally use the C  stdio functions and provide minimal or no buffering in between.  For example, if you look at [the libstdc++ implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/ext/stdio_sync_filebuf.h), you can see that it doesn't use the `std::streambuf`'s buffer pointers at all and just directly returns the result of `fread`, `getc`, and similar C I/O functions.

Going one step deeper, the `FILE` structure pointed to by the `FILE*` that `std::cin`'s `std::streambuf` contains may very well buffer data it reads from the underlying OS I/O functions (i.e. POSIX `read`, Windows `ReadFileEx`, etc), but the `FILE` structure is opaque to standard library users.  Its definition is not exposed, so you cannot inspect it except through the C stdio functions.

Answer (score 0):

`cin>>var` is a call to a function like `operator>>(cin,var)` of prototype `istream &operator>>(istream &s,sometype & var)`. `var` is passed by reference. When the input is decoded the result is just stored into `var`.

For example, you can overload that operator for your own to extract a `Date` with three fields `month`, `day` and `year`:

```
istream &operator>> (istream &is, Date &dt) {
    is >> dt.month >> dt.day >> dt.year;
    return is;
}
```

Nothing very different for standard types, just decoding and storing into the referenced variable.

Answer (score -1):

> if cin stores the data

No, it does not store the data. It links the standard input stream to the memory address. Standard input does not have to be a keyboard, since a txt file can serve as input, but cin stands for console input and what it really does is to grab your OS' console interface which is tied to the keyboard and ties the app on the chain. A way to test this is to check the assembly code of your app, you'll see only one variable, which is "var". However, there are other ways to get the input than using cin, but that is for an other question, if you are that curios.

Comment: If you do not understand the question, please ask for clarification before providing an answer that then fails to answer the question.

Comment: Sorry for the trauma. I believe that this effort to understand and answer Thang's question was satisfactory, and in case anyone would like to look at it in a different perspective, they are free and encouraged to do so.